# How can I retrieve my Java source code from a JAR file?

Tags: java, jar

I was trying to create a .jar from a .java file for a school project but now I can't read my .java file. The code I had written was overwritten somehow and I need to know how to (if possible) revert my .jar file back to the code I had written. Thanks in advance because this is a time sensitive matter.

Comment: do you have a backup or use a source code management system (SCM) like git? (OK, I know you don't! Take this as a strong suggestion to use it.) Maybe your editor has an undo/history (eclipse does have). Otherwise your work is gone...

Comment: do you have the jar file?

Comment: I do have the jar file

Comment: use intellij community - i think it comes with a decompiler built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try "decompiling" your JAR file using any JAR decompiler, such as http://www.javadecompilers.com/.

You won't get exactly the source code you originally wrote, but the decompiler will do it's best to map the `.class` files embedded in the JAR back to Java source code.

Comment: This got a HUGE part of my source code back. Thank you so much.

Comment: It got a huge part of my code back. I still need to fix a lot of stuff but it'll get done. So, yes.

Comment: Additional comments: I have now finished fixing my recovered code so I can elaborate a little more. The variable names were different so where my original code would refer to a variable by name (the program was to access a database), I would get a cannot find symbol error.

Comment: @SamHough the way to proceed is to Accept the Answer by clicking the checkmark to reward jamsesso.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse   you can right click on your project and check in history for getting old code

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not using eclipse. Just Notepad++ and the command line.